# Joining two Models with the same name in Keras Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I was trying to combine two models to concatenate outputs to a new model so that i could get prediction of both models like this

```py
model_age = load_model('age.h5')
# model_age.get_layer(name= 'model').name='predictions_1'


model_gender = load_model('gender.h5')
# model_gender.get_layer(name='model_1').name='predictions_2'

x = Input(shape=[100, 100, 3])
y_age = model_age(x)
y_gen = model_gender(x)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[y_age, y_gen])

data = cv2.imread(image)
p_age, p_gender = model.predict(data)

print(p_age)
print(p_gender)
```

but this error keeps happening that says

```
RuntimeError: (u'The name "model_1" is used 2 times in the model. All 
layer names should be unique. Layer names: ', ['input_1', u'model_1', 
u'model_1'])
```

tried solving that using the code commented above but says those models don't have a layer named 'model_1'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Models` are `Containers`, which are also `Layers`. This allows us to easily re-utilize entire networks' weights:

```py
x = Input(...)
layer_output = Dense(...)(x)
model_output = Model(...)(x)
```

You have this problem because both models were created without a name, in different python executions:

```py
# this was done:
m = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)

# instead of this:
m = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y, name='model_age')
# and this, in a different execution:
m = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y, name='model_gender')
```

This results in two models with the same default name, which is 'model_1'. Because no model can contain multiple layers with the same name (`model.get_layer(...)` wouldn't know what to do), you need to modify one of their names (or both) before merging into a single model:

```py
model_age.name = 'model_age'
model_gender.name = 'model_gender'

x = Input(shape=[100, 100, 3])
y_age = model_age(x)
y_gen = model_gender(x)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[y_age, y_gen])
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but why does input one expect a 4 dimension input if you know, when I input image it says expected 4 but got three

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you are getting an error message *4 dimensions expected, but 3 passed*. You are probably passing a single image, with shape `(height, width, channels)`, but `fit` and `predict` operate in a list of images, not in a single one.  Try to reshape `data` to `(batch, height, width, channels)` using this: `model.predict(np.expand_dims(data, 0))`.

Comment: This is not working anymore in keras version 2.0. Is there any solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the models *themselves* are both named `model_1`, not their layers.

Comment: soo the solution is ?

Comment: See @lucasdavid's answer. It seems to me that is the correct (and indeed more complete) answer to your issue. Please accept if it addressed your issue.